# Evaluating an integral using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm taking a Calculus 2 course after not taking Calculus for two years, and I'm having some trouble with some of the basics. I tried integrating this question and got $3/(9/4)^{9/4}$, but when I plugged in the $x$ values I got a large number that wasn't easily converted into a fraction. I'd appreciate some help with this question

$$\int_1^{27} 3x^{4/3} dx$$

Comment: the question is, what did you get for your anti derivative? Then we can identify your mistake (hopefully)

Comment: The antiderivative is $\displaystyle 3 {x^{4/3+1}\over 1+4/3} ={9 x^{7/3}\over 7 }$.

Comment: You're right, it is a large number. In fact, the answer I got was $\frac{19674}{7}$. But before I post how I got this, I'd like to see what your tried first.

Comment: @recursiverecursion I just realized why 9/4 is wrong and did it again, but I still don't think I did it correctly. I added 1 to 4/3 and got 7/3 then I divided 3x by 7/3 giving me (3x/7/3)^7/3 then I substituted in 27 and 1. I got 3931.14634564 and 1.79750633088 respectively.Then I subtracted the two sums and got 3929.34883931. Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're right that that is not correct. As your can see from David Mitra's comment, the anti derivative is $\frac{9x^{7/3}}{7}$. From there, if you know how to find a definite integral, it should be pretty simple. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Okay wait I think I realized what I did wrong now because of David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier for you to find the exact form if you factor the $ \frac{9}{7} $ when evaluating the integral. See below.

$$
\int_1^{27} \! 3x^{\frac{4}{3}} \, dx = [ \tfrac{9}{7} x^{\frac{7}{3}}]_1^{27} = \tfrac{9}{7} (27)^{\frac{7}{3}}-\tfrac{9}{7} (1)^{\frac{7}{3}} = \tfrac{9}{7}(2187-1)= \tfrac{19674}{7}
$$